# jQuery Now Playing Location

Tags: jquery

I currently have the jQuery plugin running on my site that shows my latest played tracks from Last.fm, how would i could it so that the artwork shows and the text shows for my new website theme.

Currently this is how it looks (awful!)

www.ibett.co.uk

Here is my new design and I want it to show bottom right so album art is in the cover and the text is in the bubble? www.ibett.co.uk/beta

Any ideas?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: You're right, I'd definitely listen to something else and bump eminem off of there.  That would look much better.  Seriously though, you just need to apply CSS rules to the classes and IDs generated by the plugin. I suggest seeing what they are in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. The elements have very clear, descriptive class names; add rules to your stylesheet to position them wherever you want. `position: absolute` might come in handy here.